# Why do static lambdas (C# 9) still have a target?

Tags: c#, .net

Static lambdas introduced in C# 9 allow us to mark a lambda expression as static to prevent it from capturing instance state.

However when you check the .Target property on the lambda it is still set, which is different to when you set an Action to a static method which has no target.

```
Action action = static () => Console.WriteLine("test");
if(action.Target != null)
{
    // action unexpectedly holds a reference
}
```

Background:
I'm trying to make a eventing system (not tied to the current event syntax) that uses weak references without needing reflection (MethodInfo). I was checking that .Target was null, but that doesn't work for static lambda, where the static lambda .Target is set to a nested singleton.

Comment: Could you please confirm that "holds a reference to the current class" is indeed true? To me it looks like `Target` points to autogenerated  nested class instance (hence unrelated to "the current class")... (Also clearly at least 4 people verified the behavior and found that indeed `Target` points to the main class' instance... any of upvoters could provide details to reproduce the behavior?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes your correct, will update question.

Comment: Consider to also clarify what exactly your concerns now... "Why C# creates class even my action does not have state on its own" or "Does class autogenerated for static action still refer to its "parent" class" or... (current answer could easily be "just because they can")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the suggestion, I added some background to my question.

Comment: Consider using static local functions instead of lambdas: they are generated with different optimizations.

Comment: @Rubidium37: Until you need to pass your static local function to a function ...

Comment: @Joshua why? They are treated the same way as normal method. Indeed they are compiled as such and delegates work with them the same way of normal methods or lambdas.

Answer (score 32):

Because static delegates are slower than delegates to instance methods.

Here's the source straight from the horse's mouth: [Comment on issue "Lambda method with no capture in static class generates instance method"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20315#issuecomment-309583018)

Here's an issue I opened awhile ago that would remove the need to do this: [[fastthis] Delegate performance being eaten up by not passing this in dedicated register](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58955)

The reason is deep in the guts of calling conventions. All delegate invocations are member function calls on the delegate method. In the ancestral platform, a static delegate compiled to only two instructions (`pop` and `jmp` indirect); however modern platforms pass arguments in registers rather than on the stack. This means an instance delegate invocation can compile to two instructions (`mov` and `jmp indirect`); however a static delegate has to compile to generate entire stack frame and copy all arguments, so it can remove the instance parameter from the argument list.

Comment: On another side this tricks is not compatible with control-flow guard in general sense, e.g. it can't be implemented as mov+jmp.